# Problems with University code on JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently attempting to complete my university coursework but I'm struggling to get my code to work. Can someone give me a helping hand?

> Now update your program so that the work of checking the lottery
>   result is done by a function called checkNumbers(). This function
>   should take the customer number and the array of winning numbers as
>   arguments. The customer number should be returned from a function
>   called getCustomerNumber(). The array of winning numbers should be
>   returned from a function called getWinningNumbers(). The display of
>   the results should be done by a function called displayResult(). The
>   whole process should be kicked off by a function called init().

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lottotask5.js">
    </script>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>DCSIS JavaScript Module TMA</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

function init() {
    new checkNumbers();
    new displayResult();
    new getWinningNumbers();
    new getCustomerNumbers();
    }

function getWinningNumbers(){ 
    var winningNumbers = [12,17,24,37,38,43];
    return winningNumbers;
    }

function getCustomerNumbers(){ 
    var customerNumbers = 12;
    return customerNumbers;
    }

function checkNumbers(customerNumbers, winningNumbers){ 
    match == false;
    for ( var i = 0; i < this.winningNumbers.length; i++){ 
        if (this.customerNumbers == this.winningNumbers[i]){    
            match == true;
            }       
        }
        return match;
    }
function displayResult(){
    if(match == true){
            alert("This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n\n" + winningNumbers[0] 
            +", "+  winningNumbers[1] +", "+ 
            winningNumbers[2] +", "+ winningNumbers[3] +", "+ 
            winningNumbers[4] +", "+ winningNumbers[5] + 
            "\n\n The Customer's Number is:\n\n"  + customerNumbers + "\n\n 
            We have a match and a winner!");
        }
        else 
        {
            alert("This Week's Winning Numbers are:\n\n" + winningNumbers[0] 
             +", "+  winningNumbers[1] +", "+ 
            winningNumbers[2] +", "+ winningNumbers[3] +", "+ 
            winningNumbers[4] +", "+ winningNumbers[5] + 
            "\n\n The Customer's Number is:\n\n"  + 13 + "\n\n Sorry you are 
            not a winner this week.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Take a look at the guide for asking good questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Please narrow the scope of his actual question to a specific uncertainty. Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi, sorry the alert will not show when i open the HTML file on FireFox

Comment: @ControlAltDel you can use `[ask]` and `[answer]` to auto-link to their How-To pages ;)

Comment: Really ? [ask] - [answer] Yes it work !

Answer (score 0):

Function displayResults cannot see members of array winningNumbers. You have to call function getWinningNumbers() from displayResult() to obtain a list of winning numbers. Same goes for customernumbers and all variables that are not global.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: would this help? if(winningNumbers == customerNumbers) etc?

Comment: No, you cannot compare two arrays this way. Just read about scope of variables, it is really not difficult. Variable can be used within a function where they have been declared